# Glue C++Qt and PyQt?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, pybind11

I embedded Python in a Qt app using Pybind11. Can we access and use PyQt created QObjects from C++ such that I can create widgets in PyQt and add them to a native C++ Qt window?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [QGIS](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS). It's a C++ application that embeds Python and from my experience has the behavior you need: Create some QObjects in PyQt (i.e. menu items) and pass them over to the C++ code to have them shown in the menu of the application.

Comment: @SebDieBln QGIS is for geographical applications. While it might *also* do that, that's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, I am aware of that. I wanted to say "take a look at the source code of QGIS" because they are doing what the OP wants to do. If I find the time, I will take a look myself and write an answer, for the moment commenting is all I can do.